# Делаю лотерею на джаве, не понимаю, почему не выводит ответ, прошу о помощи

Tags: java, массивы

Я должен написать программу, которая запрашивает 6 чисел от 0 до 49 и они должны быть уникальными (т.е. не повторяться). Программа должна искать эти числа до тех пор, пока не найдет все шесть, чтобы они совпадали. И потом показать, сколько дней или лет надо, чтобы подобрать эти числа, с учетом того, что одна подборка делается один раз в день.

Моя проблема в ряду while(!lottoNum.containsAll(numbers)) или где-то в том цикле, не понимаю почему оно не выдает результат.

Мой код:

```
package com.company;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Set<Integer> numbers = new HashSet<>();

        while (numbers.size() < 6 ){
            numbers.add(input.nextInt());
        }

        int counter = 0;
        Random random = new Random();

        Set<Integer> lottoNum = new HashSet<>();

        do {
            while (lottoNum.size() < 6) {
                lottoNum.add(random.nextInt(49) + 1);
            }
            counter++;
        } while(!lottoNum.containsAll(numbers));


        int days = counter;
        int years = days%365;

        System.out.println("It will happened in " + years);
        System.out.println(numbers);
        System.out.println(lottoNum);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам не хватало `lottoNum.clear();` перед последним `while`:

```
package com.company;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Set<Integer> numbers = new HashSet<>();

        System.out.println("Enter 6 numbers");
        while (numbers.size() < 6) {
            numbers.add(input.nextInt());
        }

        int counter = 0;
        Random random = new Random();

        Set<Integer> lottoNum = new HashSet<>();

        do {
            lottoNum.clear();
            while (lottoNum.size() < 6) {
                lottoNum.add(random.nextInt(49) + 1);
            }
            counter++;
        } while (!lottoNum.containsAll(numbers));


        int days = counter;
        int years = days % 365;

        System.out.println("It will happened in " + years);
        System.out.println(numbers);
        System.out.println(lottoNum);
    }
}
```

Другими словами, у вас лишь единожды генерировались случайные цисла, а затем они до бесконечности сравнивались с тем, что ввели вы.

Answer (score 0):

Как уже отмечено в [предыдущем ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1372205/386633), необходимо было очищать множество `lottoNum` на каждой новой итерации, иначе цикл `while` просто не выполнялся.

Следует также отметить, что в данном коде некорректно рассчитано число лет и оставшихся дней.  Как известно, среднее количество дней в году по григорианскому календарю [составляет 365,2425 суток](http://cyclowiki.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BE%D0%B4), и для нахождения количества *лет* нужно поделить рассчитанное количество дней на продолжительность года.

Также для данной задачи можно использовать метод [`Random::ints(int origin, int bound)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#ints-int-int-), генерирующий поток случайных чисел `IntStream` в заданном диапазоне:

```java
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
Set<Integer> numbers = new HashSet<>();

while (numbers.size() < 6) {
    numbers.add(input.nextInt());
}

int counter = 0;
Random random = new Random();

while (!random.ints(1, 50) // взять числа от 1 до 49 включительно
        .distinct() // неповторяющиеся
        .limit(6)   // 6 чисел
        .allMatch(numbers::contains) // чтобы все были в множестве numbers
) counter++;

int years = (int) (counter/365.2425);
int days = (int) Math.round(counter - 365.2425 * years);

System.out.printf("It will happen in %,d yrs %d days, total=%,d days%n", years, days, counter);
System.out.println(numbers);
```

Вариант ответа:

```
1 2 3 47 48 49
It will happen in 60,758 yrs 227 days, total=22,191,631 days
[48, 1, 49, 2, 3, 47]
```